# Converting a numpy array of dtype objects to dtype complex

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which I want to convert from an object to complex. If I take that array as dtype string and convert it, there is no problem:

```
In[22]: bane
Out[22]: array(['1.000027337501943-7.331085223659654E-6j',
       '1.0023086995640738-1.8228368353755985E-4j',
       '-0.017014515914781394-0.2820013864855318j'], 
       dtype='|S41')

In [23]: bane.astype(dtype=complex)
Out[23]: 
array([ 1.00002734 -7.33108522e-06j,  1.00230870 -1.82283684e-04j,
       -0.01701452 -2.82001386e-01j])
```

But when it is dtype object and I try to convert it, I get an error that a float is required. Why is this?

```
In [24]: bane.astype(dtype=object)
Out[24]: 
array(['1.000027337501943-7.331085223659654E-6j',
       '1.0023086995640738-1.8228368353755985E-4j',
       '-0.017014515914781394-0.2820013864855318j'], dtype=object)

In [25]: _.astype(dtype=complex)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f5d89c8cc46c> in <module>()
----> 1 _.astype(dtype=complex)

TypeError: a float is required
```

To convert it, I use two calls to the astype method which seems clumsy:

```
bane_obj
Out[27]: 
array(['1.000027337501943-7.331085223659654E-6j',
       '1.0023086995640738-1.8228368353755985E-4j',
       '-0.017014515914781394-0.2820013864855318j'], dtype=object)

In [28]: bane_obj.astype(dtype=str).astype(dtype=complex)
Out[28]: 
array([ 1.00002734 -7.33108522e-06j,  1.00230870 -1.82283684e-04j,
       -0.01701452 -2.82001386e-01j])
```

Comment: Sounds like a NumPy bug, maybe.

Comment: It's hard to tell where in the `numpy` code the conversion is taking place.  The string to complex conversion has probably worked for a long time, while the development of object dtypes is newer and ongoing.  What is generating this sort of object array?

Comment: An array of `dtype=np.object` could contain literally *any* kind of Python object, so I think it's understandable that the numpy developeres have not bothered to implement every conceivable type conversion rule here. Chaining together an `.astype(np.str).astype(np.complex)` actually seems seem like a quite reasonable workaround for what must be a very uncommon use-case. The real question in my mind is why you're having to deal with an `np.object` array containing complex numbers in string format in the first place!

Comment: The dtype=np.object resulted because I had several flat files I read into DataFrames and merged together prior to extracting into a np.array. These values were a mix of floats and complex so I believe it defaulted to an object datatype. I'll use my present work-around for now, Thank!

Comment: I don't think that could be the full explanation. Concatenating floats and complex floats should safely cast the result to complex. I can't see how you would end up with anything involving strings unless those columns in the `DataFrame` were already strings to begin with.

Comment: They were lists of strings to begin with, representing floats and complex values... sorry for the confusion. I went back and used a record to cast them up front as floats and complex, which as you suggested eliminated the need to deal with dtype=object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to do the following, depending on what's inside the 
object type and if there's no padding to worry about:

```
bane.view(np.complex64) or
bane.view(np.complex128)
```

However if that does not work, which it didn't for some small tuple example I tried, the following worked:

```
bane.astype(np.float).view(np.complex64)
```

Consider using numpy structures rather than objects for the base dtype, you may have an easier time over all.