# How can I read a file with complex number and convert to numpy array as complex datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, complex-data-types

I have a .excel file with complex number data and want it to convert to complex numpy array.

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
df=pd.read_excel(location, sheet_name='complex')

np_complex=df.to_numpy(dtype=complex)
```

It has worked previously, although nothing is changed (I think) but now it is raising the error

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

In line **np_complex=df.to_numpy(dtype=complex)**

Can anyone suggest the change in code?

Comment: We need more information.  Where did the error occur?  What was different previously vs now?

Comment: @hpaulj Error occured in the line "np_complex=df.to_numpy(dtype=complex)", although I do not think any thing has been changed in the excel file and code too.

Comment: have a look at `df.dtypes` to make sure the data types are correct

Comment: @JanWilamowski all datatypes are object in the excel file.

Comment: Could you show part of `df.to_numpy()`?  This should give a clearer idea of what it's trying to convert to complex.  In my tests "1+3j" and "(1+3j)"` both work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a numpy array of dtype objects to dtype complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042512/converting-a-numpy-array-of-dtype-objects-to-dtype-complex)

Comment: @JanWilamowski does it work for 2-dimensional array too. Same result with change too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. Try to rebuild then run. When I run this code it works fine my IDE. This is code [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joJDJ.png) and its result [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPt7q.png).